# Javascript Button Enable or Disable

Tags: javascript, button

I want the first function `haritaOne` work when I press the button, when I press it again, how can I run the 2nd function, `haritaTwo`?

```js
 function haritaOne() {
            var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            harita.style.left = "0px";
        }
        function haritaTwo() {
            var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
            const trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
            trafficLayer.setMap(map);
            harita.style.left = "0px";
           
        }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="javascript: haritaOne();"</a>
```

Comment: why not make it one function?

Comment: Are you expecting that the traffic overlay is removed? Because that is not how it would work.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it one function with a variable that keeps track of the state

```
var yourState = false

function yourFunction() {
  var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  harita.style.left = "0px";

  if (yourState) {
    const trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  }
  yourState = !yourState;
}
```

---

```js
var yourState = false
function yourFunction() {
  console.log('yourFunction called');

  if (yourState) {
    console.log('In True');    
  } else {
    console.log('In False');
  }
  yourState = !yourState;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="yourFunction()">Click</button>
```

Now I think you are trying to toggle the overlay which means you need to actually remove it, not just call some random function

```js
var trafficState = null;
var trafficOverlay = null;

function haritaOne() {
  // create overlay if it has yet to be created
  if (!trafficOverlay) {
    trafficOverlay = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();  
  }

  // get the new state of the overlay
  trafficState = trafficState ? null : map;
  
  //set the overlay
  trafficOverlay.setMap(trafficState);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I tried but it does the same. When pressed, haritaOne works. When pressed again, it does not operate.

Comment: Seems a bit impossible.

Comment: Are you expecting the traffic overlay to magically disappear?

Comment: I edited my answer to add what I think you are actually trying to do.

Comment: just as you said. Thank you. Thanks to you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a ternary operator in JS.

```
const counter = 0
counter>1 ? haritaTwo() : haritaOne()
```

And Add a increment line for counter in haritaOne()

```
function haritaOne() {
        var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        harita.style.left = "0px";
        counter = counter + 1
    }
```

Its just a logic explained, you can make required changes to the syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to keep both function, you may edit the button with Javascript:

```
function haritaOne(event) {
    var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    harita.style.left = "0px";
    event.target.onclick = haritaTwo;
}

function haritaTwo() {
    var harita = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    const trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
    trafficLayer.setMap(map);
    harita.style.left = "0px";
}

<a href="#" onclick="javascript: haritaOne(event);"></a>
```

You may replace `event.target.onclick = haritaTwo;` with:

```
event.target.removeEventListener(haritaOne);
event.target.addEventListener(haritaTwo);
```

Comment: can you open it more

Comment: @ErhanŞimşek what do you mean by open?

Comment: I tried but it did not work, only one function works.

Comment: @ErhanŞimşek I have edited my answer. I added `event` inside of the parentheses for `onclick`: `a href="#" onclick="javascript: haritaOne(event);">`